# How to display the calculated priced of commerce products?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have some product pricing rules that adjust the price a customer will pay.  How can I display this adjusted/calculated price to the customer?  I want to display the calculated price like a field the way the base price is displayed.

- Is there a field display setting (for example at /admin/structure/types/manage/product/display) that will do this?
- Does it have to be done through rules (if so what event and actions should be used)?

Comment: What kind of "calculate price format" are you hoping for?  You want some sort of relationship between your two price fields?

Comment: you need rules module

Comment: @alec yes, i want to show the exact amount of price field thagt generate with rules

Comment: Oh... you have rules (product pricing rules that run when calculating sell price of a product?) that calculate the price...(is that correct?) And it's that calculated price which you're trying to display in a field?

Comment: yes exactly @alec

Comment: I re-wrote the question for you.  I'm not sure if you can approve that edit yourself or not, but either way, the question should be clarified so people can help you more easily.  Unfortunately I don't know off-hand how to achieve what you're trying to do, but it's a relatively simple goal so someone should be able to help!

Comment: by rules action 'Calculating the sale price of a product' it will display automaticly your 'calculated price' to customer, and it be also used in commerce order.

Comment: EDIT to my last comment: 'Calculate the sale price of a product' it's a trigger event, then add your conditions and actions, in actios you have: 'multiply price by a variable', or 'set price ammount to certain value', or ....., for both, before that action, add variables as needed, and make your calculations, then use actions described here.

Comment: @pinueve can you explain?  does the rule you're suggesting add extra modification to the price?  This question is about displaying the price with its existing (not additional) modifications/calculations.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/22625018

Comment: @pinueve that video's not what this question is about.  Soheil already has product pricing rules.  This question is _how to display in a field (think node display mode) what the calculated price will be_.

Comment: That video shows the price field automatically displaying the calculated price.  That's apparently not happening for @soheil.

Comment: @soheil did you find a solution for this?

Comment: no and i did it in another way

Comment: thx anyway for your time

Comment: thx anyway for your time

Answer (score 1):

When a price field is rendered using the "Formatted price" display formatter, it has a setting for you to choose between displaying the original price as loaded or the calculated sell price for the current user. That second one is the default, so as long as you are using product pricing rules properly (as indicated in the comments), this should just work for you.

If for some reason it isn't you'll need to find and review your display settings for the price field on your various product types. Because the price field that appears on a product display comes from the product entity directly, you have to adjust its field display settings there instead of on the relevant node type. You should find them under **Administration > Store > Products > Product types**. Click the **manage display** link beside your product type and see what it says.

If you get stuck, feel free to join us in the #commerce channel in the Drupal Slack!

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I'd like to join commerce channel.

Comment: Cool! You can find instructions for getting connected here: https://www.drupal.org/slack

Once you're in, join the #commerce channel. There's always folks around. : )